# How to deal with payment scam through apple calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, calendar, apple-pay

I upgraded to latest version of iOS and link my debit card to apply pay a few days ago. After that I start receiving a very suspicious invite on my iPhone calendar. I ignored it and on advice from my friend, disabled "Events found in apps". However, 2 days later, when I wake up, I received the same event again, and most shockingly the phone was at the payment screen, waiting for me to authorise the payment of $19,99 through my thumbprint. Unfortunately I did not take a screenshot of this as I immediately turn off and on my phone to get rid of it.

I checked both my gmail and yahoo mail accounts that are linked to my phone, including the spam folder, but did not find any suspicious email.

I had contacted apple support, but they did not even know about the disable event found in apps feature. Really worried about the security of my phone now and thinking of deleting apple calendar or removing apple pay. Any advise will be appreciated.

[image: Suspicious invite]

[image: Disabled event found in apps]

[image: New invite]

Comment: Try changing the colour of the Singapore holidays calendar to check it isn't that, then try the same with Work calendar to find which one it has come from.

Comment: It came from iCloud, Work. I did not share that calendar with anyone.

Comment: I'm receiving the same "message" in my calendar and I can't figure out what channel was used. Icloud apparently but... how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the solution, which fights the consequences not the reason, is to create another iCloud calendar named, for instance, "Spam" and move scam event(s) there without accepting/declining it (them). Then just delete this "Spam" calendar choosing 'Do not notify' when asked.

I think all this is due to [hack](https://www.yahoo.com/tech/500-million-yahoo-confirms-biggest-205407604.html) of Yahoo mail when some people got access to many Yahoo addresses (about 500 million) and now they are sending those iCloud calendar scams.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since that apple support is of no help, this is the best that can be done. Weird that Apple allow any random with your email to spam invites at you.